# Call to undefined method App\Models\StudentModel::createToken()

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

[This is my Models code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ur3W.png)Here, `StudentModel` is my custom model which extends **Authenticable**.But I get this error `App\Models\StudentModel::createToken()`.

[This is the providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rau4E.png)

[And this is the controller part where i'm getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLdgk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `use` the HasApiTokens trait that you imported on your User Model:

```
class StudentModel extends Authenticatable 
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After customizing the `user` model, you have to modify the auth configuration.

In `config/auth.php`, you change the following code.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        // 'model' => App\User::class,
        'model' => App\Models\StudentModel::class,
    ],
    ...
],
```

Comment: So, you should share your information in more detail. Please! You can update your post.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan config:clear` after modifying `config/auth.php`?

Comment: question updated..No didn't run that command.